# Local Storage me lanza error al utilizar JSON.parse()

Tags: angular, local-storage

Cuando quiero obtener los datos desde localStorage con `JSON.parse` me marca el siguiente error que se muestra en la siguiente imagen y linea de código.

```
import { CieoM } from './../../models/cieo-m';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CieoMLstorageService {

  cieoMs: any[];

  constructor() {
    this.cieoMs = []
  }

  createCieoM(cieoM: CieoM): void {
    this.cieoMs.unshift(cieoM);
    localStorage.setItem('cieoMs', JSON.stringify(this.cieoMs));

  }
  getCioMs(): void {
    this.cieoMs=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cieoMs'));//error ocurrido 
  }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna solución que me podrían brindar? Y un gracias de antemano por sus respuestas

Comment: Esto quiere decir que no existe el item en localStorage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quiere decir que local storage te puede arrojar un `null` o  un `string`, pero `JSON.parse` no acepta `null` como parametro.

Debes comprobar que el resultado no sea un nulo.

```
 getCioMs(): void {
    const dato = localStorage.getItem('cieoMs')
    //Solo entra si no es nulo. 
    if(dato) this.cieoMs=JSON.parse(dato);
    //ejemplo de resolución.
    else mostrarMensajeService.mostrarError() 
  }
```

Comment: Gracias funciona

Comment: @Gamboa te recomiendo que, si considertas que una respuesta soluciona tu pregunta, la marques como aceptada